# Import a json file, but only use the information one line at a time

Tags: python, json, sorting, if-statement, variables

I'm writing because I think what I'm asking would need multiple different functions to pull off and I'm not sure how that should be structured.

```
import json

filename = rs.OpenFileName("Open JSON File", filter)

#Read JSON data into the results variable
if filename:
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    results = json.load(f)
```

To import the data into the results variable, and say this is the data in the json file.

```
{"votes": {"funny": 2, "useful": 5, "cool": 1}, "user_id": "harveydennis", "name": "Jasmine Graham", "url": "http://example.org/user_details?userid=harveydennis", "average_stars": 3.5, "review_count": 12, "type": "user"}
{"votes": {"funny": 1, "useful": 2, "cool": 4}, "user_id": "njohnson", "name": "Zachary Ballard", "url": "https://www.example.com/user_details?userid=njohnson", "average_stars": 3.5, "review_count": 12, "type": "user"}
{"votes": {"funny": 1, "useful": 0, "cool": 4}, "user_id": "david06", "name": "Jonathan George", "url": "https://example.com/user_details?userid=david06", "average_stars": 3.5, "review_count": 12, "type": "user"}
{"votes": {"funny": 6, "useful": 5, "cool": 0}, "user_id": "santiagoerika", "name": "Amanda Taylor", "url": "https://www.example.com/user_details?userid=santiagoerika", "average_stars": 3.5, "review_count": 12, "type": "user"}
{"votes": {"funny": 1, "useful": 8, "cool": 2}, "user_id": "rodriguezdennis", "name": "Jennifer Roach", "url": "http://www.example.com/user_details?userid=rodriguezdennis", "average_stars": 3.5, "review_count": 12, "type": "user"}
```

Now I'd like to have an if then statement use that and assign to a separate variable, but it goes line by line.

if "funny" >= 5 then "user_id" = variableName

do {

Then I'll contain a do command below that'll use that variable, the  Everything will restart with the next entry (next votes line) until there aren't any entries left.

Is this even possible?  If so how would that look?

Comment: That's [JSONLines](https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Technically your file is not json, but you can read a file line by line and ‘results = json.loads(line)’ for each line.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your problem correctly, you can iterate over the lines in your file and generate a json object with every line

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        current_json = json.loads(line)
        your_awesome_function(current_json["votes"]["funny"])
```

Comment: and then I'd be able to assign variables according to an if then statement with that?

Comment: You can access the data like this `if current_json["votes"]["funny"] >= 5: my_variable = current_json["user_id"]`. Note that you need to use this inside of the for loop, otherwise your value will get overwritten in the next loop iteration.